# What does this syntax mean in Haskell: ([]:_)

Tags: haskell

I saw this at a function ([]:_)

Cannot find a definition of it (Google doesn't work well with symbols). So what is it anyway?

```
type Mat a = [[a]]

myTranspose :: Mat a -> Mat a
myTranspose ([]:_) = []
myTranspose p = (map head p) : myTranspose (map tail p)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is pattern matching for a list of lists. It **matches with a list with at least one element where the first element is the empty list**. For instance `[[]]`, or `[[], [2,4]]`, `[[], [], [1,4], [2], [5]]`.

A list in Haskell is defined as a linked list with two constructors: `[]`, the empty list, and `(a:as)` the "cons" where `a` is the "head" (the first element of the list), and `as` the tail (a list that contains the remaining elements).

Furthermore the underscore `_` is used as a "*don't care*" variable. So it means that we look for a *cons* pattern `(a:as)`, where `a` (the first element) is an empty list `[]`, and `as` is `_` so we are not interested in the remaining elements of the list.

In the case of the `myTranspose` function, it will thus result in an empty list if you give it a list of lists with the first item being an empty list.